# Using Substring and Convert Datetime Sql Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
declare @date char(10)
set @date = '11.08.1982'
select substring(@date,1,2)+ '/'+ 
SUBSTRING(@date,3,1)+ '/'+ SUBSTRING(@date,4,4) as resultat
```

I want to use `CONVERT` function to convert the result to datetime. How can I do this?

Comment: What in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) didn't you understand, or  what about your attempt(s) didn't work?

Comment: The result is `11/./08.1` were you trying to do `REPLACE(@date,'.','/')`?

Comment: i want to use convert function to convert my result in datetime

Comment: how to use substring and convert together ?

Comment: By wrapping `CONVERT` around your `SUBSTRING` expression. The documentation gives plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-cast-with-arithmetic-operators). Again, what about the documentation didn't you understand? What about *your* attempts didn't work?

Comment: What is `11.08.1982` anyway? 11th August or 8th November?

Comment: august not november

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert this to date and time, however you can use replace function :

```
select replace(@data, '.', '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is pretty good about picking up the format of a date with no conversion format.  So, this works on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6340092b665ea1982b76be8af7ec6745), assuming you intend MM.DD.YYYY for the format:

```
select convert(date, '11.08.1982')
```

If you want DD.MM.YYYY, then you can explicitly use the "104" format:

```
select convert(date, '11.08.1982', 104)
```

You don't have a time component, so I converted these to `date`.  The same works for `datetime`.

Comment: but if i have in my variable a values like this '11081982' how can use CONVERT and SUBSTRING

Comment: @badiszakaria . . . This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask a *new* question with clear explanation, sample data and desired results.